# Google Cloud DNS subdomain forwarding

Tags: dns, cloud

We use Google Cloud DNS and have a domain name subdomain.domain.com that we would like redirected to subdomain.microsoftonline.com. I know from previous jobs we've used GoDaddy which allows you to forward a sub domain. I'm not seeing that as an option in the Google Cloud DNS and was wondering if anyone could assist?

Answer (score -1):

Updated Answer:
Navigate to Google Cloud DNS
1. Click Add Record set
2. Enter your sub domain in DNS Name
3. Select Resource record type "CNAME"
4. In Canonical name enter the destination sub domain

Hit Save

As @Fanatique mentioned. The below step is for adding a DNS record for a subdomain

Navigate to Google Cloud DNS
1. Click Add Record set
2. Enter your sub domain in DNS Name
3. Select Record Type "A"
4. Enter IP address of your server you want to point your subdomain

Click Create

That's it. Let me know if you need any help in Google Cloud

Comment: This solution is for adding a DNS record for a subdomain, not for redirecting a subdomain to a different URL.